# How can I put double quotes inside a string within an ajax JSON response from php?

Tags: php, ajax, escaping, json

I receive a JSON response in an Ajax request from the server. This way it works:

{ "a" : "1", "b" : "hello 'kitty'" }

But I did not succeed in putting double quotes around *kitty*.

When I convert " to \x22 in the Ajax response, it is still interpreted as " by JavaScript and I cannot parse the JSON.

Should I also escape the \ and unescape later (which would be possible)?

How to do this?

*Edit:* I am not sure if i expressed it well: I want this string inside of "b" *after* the parse:

hello "kitty"

If necessary I could also add an additional step after the parse to convert "b", but I guess it is not necessary, there is a more elegant way so this happens automatically?

*Edit2:* The ajax page is generated by php. I tried several things now to create the value of b, all result in JSON parse error on the page:

```
  $b = 'hello "kitty"';      

  // no 1:
  //$b = str_replace('"',"\x22",$b);

  // or no 2:
  // $b = addslashes($b);  

  // or no 3: 
  $b = str_replace('"','\"',$b);

  echo '{ "a" : "1", "b" : "' . $b . '"}';
```

*Edit3:* This solution finally works:

```
$b = 'hello "kitty"';      
$b = str_replace('"','\\"',$b); 
echo '{ "a" : "1", "b" : "' . $b . '"}';
```

Comment: `\"` is OK and `\u0022` is OK, but `\x22`, though it is valid in a JavaScript string literal, is not allowed in JSON.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just escape it with a backslash:

```
> JSON.stringify({"a": 5, "b": 'a "kitty" mighty odd'})
{"a":5,"b":"a \"kitty\" mighty odd"}
> JSON.parse('{"a":5,"b":"a \\"kitty\\" mighty odd"}')
Object
  a: 5
  b: a "kitty" mighty odd
  __proto__: Object
```

JSON parsers recognize `\"` inside double-quoted strings as a double quote. Note that in the second example, the double-backslash is needed because there's a Javascript parser pass, then another JSON parser pass.

Comment: thanks a lot! you save my day. this works for me now:   $b = str_replace('"','\\"',$b); - karlthorwald - aka

Comment: @user89021: please read the bit about escaping backslashes too.

Comment: You saved my week.  Because of the multiple parsers it turns out I had to add three slashes.  It finally works!

Answer (score 2):

use just json_encode (any PHP element ), it will automatically parses.

Comment: yeah, but my php version is to old, ubuntu hardy does not have it yet, only PHP 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10 here - karthorwald - aka

Comment: i will check again, because 5.2 should have it. last time it wasn't there :o

Answer (score 1):

A little off-topic, you could use JavaScript/NodeJS on your server and use ES6 template literals (the backticks `` used around "Christian"), but 7 years later you probably already use NodeJS :)

```
var myJSON = {
    "name": {
        "first": `"Christian"`,
        "last": "Broberg"
    },
    "age": 49,
    "skills": [ "JavaScript", "React", "NodeJS" ],
    "married": false,
    "superpowers": null
}
```