# Escaping javascript variable double quotes

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm using Ajax calls to get some variables data from the DB.
some of my data stored on the database contains double quotes (").

when I'm trying to display the variable :

```
value="'+ucontent+'"
```

the string gets cut in the middle (of course)

I have tried using escape() but im getting a non readable result - something with %4%2 etc...

how can i escape the double quotes in the variable and still keep a readable string...
BTW - I'm using UTF8 characters.

Comment: Can you add more code? Like how are you handling the ajax response and generating it on server?

Comment: The quotes should already be JavaScript data, so it is unclear what the problem is. Where are you trying to display the variable? Is `value` an HTML attribute that you are going to use with `innerHTML`?

Comment: Did you tried replacing double quote with some other character ??

Comment: What is the server side language?

Comment: you are trying to display value when? After ajax call? where does data came from? how do you try to display data?

Comment: What language are you using to return the data from the database? Could you not clean this result on the server side before passing it to the clientside?

Comment: value="'+ucontent+'" is javascript code ... im getting the value directly from the inputbox (document.getElementById('valuebox')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decodeURIComponent()
```

might be helpful

what escape actually does is replace some characters with a hexadecimal escape sequence.
That is the reason why you are getting unreadable string like %4%2.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what language in server side you are using.

If it is php, then use `json_encode` to encode the response string.

If it is ruby(rails), then use `escape_javascript` to escape the response string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `\"` if you don't use an encoder. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732409/how-can-i-put-double-quotes-inside-a-string-within-an-ajax-json-response-from-ph).

Comment: i cant add it because it is the user input ... im taking the user input and transfering it to another input on the form. I want to use something like PHP addslashes ...

Comment: @liorr If you're processing it at all, you can certainly add it :)  So when you are "taking the user input and transferring it", you can mess with the user input all you like. In your Javascript, you stick the user input in a variable, and then use a `replace` or equivalent.