# How to get a JSON response for ItemLookup/Search using Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: xml, xslt, jsonp, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to get the details of Amazon product from its ASIN. The product API allows to do a Itemlookup with `ASIN`, but the return value is in `XML`.

I want to do this call for Itemlookup from client side, so would like to do a `JSONP` call, which I couldn't find.

I found some articles on the web to convert the XML to `JSON` format using XSLT stylesheet:

(a) https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/src/tip/examples/json-results.py

I tried using this `python-amazon-product-api` and this example, but I couldn't get a `JSON` return.

(b) http://www.kokogiak.com/gedankengang/2006/05/consuming-amazons-web-api-directly.html

The request I tried to send is:

```
http://xml-us.amznxslt.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=[ACCESS KEY]&AssociateTag=[ASSOCIATE TAG]&ContentType=text%2Fjavascript&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B008IEGS9W&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes&Service=AWSECommerceService&Style=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.delphiforums.com%2Fdelphidocsz%2Famazon%2Fjson.xsl&Timestamp=2012-09-04T06%3A40%3A11Z&Signature=AGOqXvVSeMp3YyVkT4mGNXVx0cFGG%2Bh%2FdAebevbbF9o%3D
```

Please help with getting a JSON format with `Amazon product API`.

---

The OP can run this style-sheet (input document not used) to determine his XSLT version.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head><title>About your XSLT Processor</title></head> 
   <body>
     <ul>
       <li>xsl:version=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" /></li>
       <li>xsl:vendor=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')" /></li>
       <li>xsl:vendor-url=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor-url')" /></li>
       <li>xsl:product-name=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:product-name')" /></li>
       <li>xsl:product-version=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:product-version')" /></li>
       <li>xsl:is-schema-aware=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')" /></li>
       <li>xsl:supports-serialization=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:supports-serialization')" /></li>
       <li>xsl:supports-backwards-compatibility=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:supports-backwards-compatibility')" /></li>
       <li>msxsl:version=<xsl:value-of select="system-property('msxsl:version')" /></li>
     </ul>  
   </body>  
 </html>  
</xsl:template>
      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please supply a sample of the return value XML, and your particular required JSON format. It should then be possible to write an XSLT style-sheet to transform it into JSON. What version of XSLT can you use? 1.0? or 2.0?

Comment: Please find the XML response at https://gist.github.com/3626354 .

I would like to extract the product Title, details page link, the medium image of the product. I'm not sure of the version of the XSLT. How to find it out?

Comment: Please run the stylesheet that I have included, and report results.

Comment: Also, given the document you have linked, please list the JSON output that you would expect.

Comment: And what if the Title contains a double quote (") character? Will you be satisfied with a simple solution that ignores this possiblity? Or do you want a robust solution that JSON encodes values (that is to say escapes the double quotes)? (Refer Max Shawabkeh's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732409)

Comment: +1 Any resolution to this question?

Comment: The question still lacks what the desired JSON output format it.  A simple Google search will provide hits to general XML->JSON conversion, but such solutions may be too general in this case.  As for things like double quotes (assuming a custom JSON output is desired), you can use regex if using XSLT 2.0.  If stuck with XSLT 1.0, see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7523245/719934](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7523245/719934).

Comment: @thomastinu, Please, *edit* the question and provide: 1) the XML document you have (from AWS); and 2) The exact JSON object you want to have.

Comment: @thomastinu if the answer below worked for you, consider accepting the answer, and marking the question as resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Try either of these ::

1. [Amazon JSON API](https://github.com/christianhellsten/amazon-json-api) - This is a ruby webservice to pass through requests and translate the responses to JSON.
2. Try any of these Javascript functions to convert the XML you already have into JSON :

   1. http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/
   2. http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json
   3. http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/
   4. http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html

I've tried thomasfrank myself. Its easy and works well :)

Answer (score 0):

(disclosure) I’m Max and I’m a cofounder of Zinc (zinc.io). Our API produces a JSON response for both pricing and the product details page. Here’s a typical response for ASIN details: https://www.dropbox.com/s/peccdc1m2j34e0d/B018QPI98A.json?dl=0. If you're interested, see here: docs.zincapi.com

Comment: Absolutely recommended