# Can I get data as json array from Amazon API?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

Have anyone use Amazon API for get data feed?
I want to get data set from Amazon API but I can't get data as a json array.
It gives only XML data set.
Can I get data set as a json array?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be as of now. Just translate xml to json as given in the answer to [Amazon Product Advertising API : How to get a JSON response for ItemLookup/Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258139/amazon-product-advertising-api-how-to-get-a-json-response-for-itemlookup-searc)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Can I search offer for key words in Amazon?