# For CSS inline style escape

Tags: jquery, css

In my project, I use the ajax to send the data to backstage and if there are css inline style like follow:

```
<p><span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84); font-family: medium-content-serif-font, Georgia, Cambria, &quot;Times New Roman&quot;, Times, serif; font-size: 21px; letter-spacing: -0.063px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Making myself so vulnerable was terrifying. It was difficult, telling the truth of my body, subjecting myself to the opinions others would inevitably form about my body if they didn’t have them already.</span></p>
```

It will be forbiddened and if I clear the style like follow:

```
<p>Making myself so vulnerable was terrifying. It was difficult, telling the truth of my body, subjecting myself to the opinions others would inevitably form about my body if they didn’t have them already.</p>
```

It works.

So are there methods I can only escape the inline style for this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Did you remove span also? so you want to remove only style or style with span too?

Comment: I want to escape the inline style rather than remove it.

Comment: Please post your ajax call, just the minimum required to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put double quotes inside a string within an ajax JSON response from php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732409/how-can-i-put-double-quotes-inside-a-string-within-an-ajax-json-response-from-ph)

Comment: Thank you, but it seems not a double quotes problem...